# Geth node in light mode basic setup

Tags: go-ethereum, full-node

I just installed geth node and want to start it in light mode on my ubuntu home machine. This is the command I run.

geth --http.api eth,web3,debug,txpool,net,shh,db,admin,debug --http  --syncmode light --http.port=8547

However, it just prints these logs. Can someone help with simple command to run light node

```
NFO [04-07|22:59:35.444] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=2 static=0
INFO [04-07|22:59:46.438] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=6 static=0
INFO [04-07|22:59:56.457] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=6 static=0
INFO [04-07|23:00:07.464] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=6 static=0
WARN [04-07|23:00:08.174] UDP connection queries failed            count=80
INFO [04-07|23:00:17.471] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=4 static=0
INFO [04-07|23:00:27.489] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=6 static=0
WARN [04-07|23:00:32.193] UDP connection queries failed            count=100
INFO [04-07|23:00:37.495] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=3 static=0
INFO [04-07|23:00:48.494] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7 static=0
INFO [04-07|23:00:58.499] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=8 static=0
WARN [04-07|23:01:06.216] UDP connection queries failed            count=120
INFO [04-07|23:01:08.507] Looking for peers                        peercount=0 tried=7 static=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your light node just boostrapped. It needs to find a peers on the nework, which will take time. It is required to find peers to download Ethereum state. Once there is new peer, the `peercount` will be increased. From official [website](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/tutorials/run-light-node-geth/):

> Once launched, Geth will begin connecting to other nodes on Ethereum -
> known as "peers". The process of connecting to peers may take a while.
>
> When your Geth node has enough peers, it will import headers from new
> blocks on the chain.
>
> When new block headers no longer have an "age", Geth will be synced to
> the chain's head.

Comment: running for more than 12 hours and still same, also what does this log line means



WARN [04-07|23:00:32.193] UDP connection queries failed